# How to detect a collision in a Windows Store apps?

Tags: vb.net, collision-detection

This is my first question on Stack Overflow's possible that I'll make mistakes. (and I use a internet translator)

I do not know how to detect collision in Windows Store apps. On Windows Forms it looks like this:

```
If Player.Bounds.IntersectsWith (Enemy1.Bounds) Then
    'do something
End If
```

**Please give me function that returns a boolean. Thank you for all the answers.**

You can give me c# code i will convert it!

Answer (score 1):

This is just a function with a boolean value as result. You can try this with two simple controls, with buttons for example.

You can create a new project, add two buttons and put them away, then launch the window app, then overlap them and relaunch the app.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If Button1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Button2.Bounds) Then 'this return true/false
        MsgBox("Collision detected")
    End If
end sub
```

Comment: I know this but in Windows Universal Aplications function Rectangle.IntersectsWith not exsists :(